# What is "Sisu means data"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I saw that on a laptop sticker(owned by a girl majoring in computer science) and I thought Sisu may [typify the Finnish spirit](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sisu), but I wonder how it relates to "data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sisu in the quote doesn't refer to the Finnish spirit. Instead, it refers to a San Francisco based data-driven technology [company](https://www.sisu.ai/) that helps its clients make better decisions by analyzing their data across various Key Performance Indicators.

Their logo looks like the following, maybe something similar was also on the laptop sticker in question.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense! The school is located in California!